# Node.js scalability problems in Windows Azure

Tags: node.js, performance, rest, azure

For an academic essay I'm comparing Asp.Net and Node.Js web application deployed in windows azure.

I'm testing and measuring a request that calls a rest service that just holds for 7 seconds and responds to the request after it. The idea is to measure how Node.Js and Asp.Net will behave in this situation.

node.js is very fast in load tests with 250 users when I test in my own computer. The average time of response is around of 7 seconds, just the time of the rest call response. Asp.Net is around 1-2 seconds slower.

When I do the same test with these apps deployed in Azure, the results change a lot. While Asp.Net keeps almost the same results, Node.js takes more than 100 seconds to respond with the same test, and it doesn't matter the size of cloud service.

Here is the function that calls the URL that holds for 7 seconds:

```
function sleep(response, request) {
    var currentQuery = url.parse(request.url).query;
    var time = querystring.parse(currentQuery).time;
    
    var options = {
        host: 'whatever.cloudapp.net',
        port: 80,
        path: '/?sleep=' + time,
        method: 'GET'
    };
    
    http.request(options, function () {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' });
        response.write('response ok.');
        response.end();
    }).end();
```

What is happening? Why does node.js seem to be not scalable with I/O bounds when deployed in windows azure?

Comment: You use Cloud Services and not Web Apps intentionally?

Comment: Yes, I just choose because it is easy to manage and has more tools to measure. But I'll try to change it to WebSites anyway. Do you think that it can be a problem?

Comment: Maybe. Or maybe not :-). It depends on many factors - would be helpful to chat, actually. But let's start here - what is the VM size you are using for the Cloud Service?

Comment: @AlexBelotserkovskiy, Actually it doesn't matter. I've already tried since the ExtraSmall to the Large size. The tests have almost the same bad results. The requests to the REST service seems to be queued. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @AlexBelotserkovskiy It just works fine with WebSite. But why the same source code have such a different results when deployed in a Cloud Service. Considering a load test with 250 virtual users calling the same URL. As I said, the node server receive the request and calls an rest service that hold for 7 seconds before return an answer. With the WebSite deployment, the average test time was 8,69 seconds. With cloud service deployment, the same load test with same amount of users, the average test time was 62,5 seconds! what is happening with Cloud Service and Node.JS together? Why so slow?

Comment: Very difficult to say. I put that into the answer. I need to say that there is no ideal answer to your question like "it is because...". In a cloud world, a lot happens, and you may encounter the issue when the instance is very busy with something else. I would offer you to try test Web Apps as tey looks like more suitable for your testing methodology, from my POV, and Service Fabric as a new compute offering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference between CS and WA is not normal, not with these numbers you refer to. But it is very hard to give the exact answer why it happens. It may be "noisy neighborhood", may be the long time to run for a first time (that may be solved for WA with Always On in settings, and with Cloud Services a little longer, but it can be solved), because there is the idle timeout, and CS WebRole, for example, will recycle after, as far as i remember, 20 minutes of idle.

The simplest way to eliminate the possibility that it can be the intermittent issue is to redeploy the CS to the different region using the large VM in the beginning.

I suspect that the performance difference reason may be in the [different nature of CS and WA](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/) - CS is more like a VM that will spin out when you deploy the solution, and WA likely not.

If you have the opportunity, you may analyze what is going on, using the [official performance CS guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-performance-profiling-cloud-services/).

And i would try to test the new Service Fabric offering instead of the classic CS, as that may gives some interesting insights into the cloud offerings.

Comment: It's not the answer at all. I'm still don't know what's going on. But anyway, thank you for help me find a way to get the results that I was looking for.